# Haskell second smallest value in list

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to write a function `secondSmallest` that returns the second smallest value in the list, or Nothing if there is no such value. Also, if the smallest value of the list occurs multiple times, it's also the second smallest. For example:

- `secondSmallest [1.0]` -->  `Nothing`
- `secondSmallest [1,1,2]` -->  `Just 1`
- `secondSmallest [5,3,7,2,3,1]`  -->  `Just 2`

Here's what I have so far:

```
secondSmallest :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
secondSmallest []       = Nothing
secondSmallest [x]      = Nothing
secondSmallest (x:y:xs) = Just secondSmallest ((if x < y then x else y):xs)
```

Comment: Well right now you only showed some examples and a signature. What have you tried?

Comment: This is not a question, but a "write code for me" request.

Comment: Hint: does a list with one element has a second smallest element?

Comment: What you here basically have written is something that looks like a `minimum`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I thought I could modify that into a second smallest function, but haven't succeeded. That's why I didn't put the code in the question at first, because it's basically `minimum`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Using `sort`

A lazy approach is by using [**`sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort). `sort` returns a sorted list, but in a lazy manner, and obtaining the *k*-th element, with *O(n)* for a fixed element, and in case we enumerate up to the *k*-th element, it will take *O(n log k)*, we can thus perform pattern matching on the `sort` result, and then return the second element, like:

```
import Data.List(sort)

secondSmallest :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
secondSmallest l | (_:x:_) <- sort l = Just x
                 | otherwise = Nothing
```

## By using an accumulator

Another approach is by using an *accumulator*. An accumulator is a parameter in the recursion that we (optionally) update and then pass an updated version. In this case we can use a 2-tuple that contains the smallest, and one-but-smallest element. So now we implement another function

```
secondSmallest' :: Ord a => (a, a) -> [a] -> a
secondSmallest' (s1, s2) ...
```

where `s1 <= s2` always holds. Now there are some cases we need to consider:

1. the list is empty, in that case we reached the end of the list, and thus can return `s2`, the thus far obtained second minimum

   ```
   secondSmallest' (_, s2) [] = s2
   ```
2. the list is not empty, and the head `x` is greater than or equal to `s2`, in that case the thus far two smallest elements remain the same, so we can pass the 2-tuple unchanged and we recurse on the tail of the list.

   ```
   secondSmallest' s@(s1, s2) (x:xs) | x >= s2 = secondSmallest' s xs
   ```
3. in case the head `x` is greater than or equal to `s1`, but less than `s2`, then we know that this is the *newest* second smallest, so in that case we construct a new 2-tuple with `(s1, x)` and recurse on the tail of the list

   ```
                                     | x >= s1 = secondSmallest' (s1, x) xs
   ```
4. in case the head `x` is less than `s1`, then we obtained a new *smallest* element. In that case `s1` is the newest smallest element:

   ```
                                     | otherwise = secondSmallest' (x, s1) xs
   ```

So now we implemented a function that - given we already have two *thus* far smallest elements - can return the second smallest element:

```
secondSmallest' :: Ord a => (a, a) -> [a] -> a
secondSmallest' (_, s2) [] = s2
secondSmallest' s@(s1, s2) (x:xs) | x >= s2 = secondSmallest' s xs
                                  | x >= s1 = secondSmallest' (s1, x) xs
                                  | otherwise = secondSmallest' (x, s1) xs
```

But now we still have not solved the main problem, how do we obtain the first 2-smallest elements. Basically there are three cases here:

1. in case the list contains at least two elements, and the first element is less than or equal to the second element, we take the first element as the smallest and the second as the second smallest element, and perform a call on the rest of the list and we wrap the result in a `Just` constructor:

   ```
   secondSmallest (x1:x2:xs) | x1 <= x2 = Just (secondSmallest' (x1, x2) xs)
   ```
2. in case the list contains at least two elements but the first element is greater than the second, then we take the first element as the second smallest, and the second element as the smallest, we again perform a call to the `secondSmallest'` function, and wrap the result in a `Just` constructor:

   ```
                             | otherwise = Just (secondSmallest' (x2, x1) xs)
   ```
3. in case the list contains less items, we can not calculate the second smallest, since there is no second smallest, so we return `Nothing`:

   ```
   secondSmallest _ = Nothing
   ```

so in full we get:

```
secondSmallest :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
secondSmallest (x1:x2:xs) | x1 <= x2 = Just (secondSmallest' (x1, x2) xs)
                          | otherwise = Just (secondSmallest' (x2, x1) xs)
secondSmallest _ = Nothing

secondSmallest' :: Ord a => (a, a) -> [a] -> a
secondSmallest' (_, s2) [] = s2
secondSmallest' s@(s1, s2) (x:xs) | x >= s2 = secondSmallest' s xs
                                  | x >= s1 = secondSmallest' (s1, x) xs
                                  | otherwise = secondSmallest' (x, s1) xs
```

Note that `secondSmallest'` is in fact a `fold` pattern, so we can write it like:

```
secondSmallest :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
secondSmallest (x1:x2:xs) | x1 <= x2 = Just (secondSmallest' (x1, x2) xs)
                          | otherwise = Just (secondSmallest' (x2, x1) xs)
secondSmallest _ = Nothing

secondSmallest' :: Ord a => (a, a) -> [a] -> [a]
secondSmallest' t = snd . foldr f t
    where f s@(s1, s2) x | x >= s2 = s
                         | x >= s1 = (s1, x)
                         | otherwise = (x, s1)
```

Comment: I think it's actually O(n log k), which is fine for k=2.

Comment: @dfeuer: that's what I meant with *fixed* `k`. If you take that as a precondition, then it is linear. If it is a variable, then it is indeed as far as I know *O(n log k)*.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use a fold. Let's start by writing a type for the accumulator:

```
import Data.List (foldl')

data Acc a = None
           | One a
           | Two {sml :: a, sndsml :: a}

finish :: Acc a -> Maybe a
finish Two{sndsml = r} = Just r
finish _ = Nothing
```

Now,

```
secondSmallest
  :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
secondSmallest = finish . foldl' go None
  where
    go None a = One a
    go (One b) a
      | b < a = Two{sml=b, sndsml=a}
      | otherwise = Two{sml=b, sndsml=a}
    go r@Two{sml=b, sndsml=c} a
      | a < b = Two{sml=a,sndsml=b}
      | a < c = Two{sml=b,sndsml=a}
      | otherwise = r

-- For extra efficiency in some cases
{-# INLINABLE secondSmallest #-}
```

GHC is clever enough to compile this definition into something just like Willem Van Onsem's solution. However, when passed a "good producer" for list fusion (e.g., `secondSmallest (map (\x -> x * (x - 50)) xs)`), the fold-based version will generally be more efficient.

Comment: Alternative: the accumulator is `(Maybe a, Maybe a)`, initialized to `(Nothing, Nothing)`.  Your `None` case is `(Nothing, Nothing)` and your `One` case is `(Just x, Nothing)`.  At the finish, return `snd acc`.

Comment: It would let us eliminate the `Acc a` type and `finish`, and write the whole thing in fewer lines of code. Better is a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Wrote it up into another solution. People can decide for themselves which one they like, but I think the examples of different approaches are instructive.

Answer (score 2):

[dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477667/dfeuer)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50092117/849891) gave me an idea,

```
import Data.List (foldl', sort)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

secondSmallest :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
secondSmallest = listToMaybe . take 1 . drop 1 . foldl' g [] 
    where 
    g acc x = f acc `seq` take 2 (sort (x:acc))
    f [a,b] = a < b
    f _     = True
```

The code is short, but *probably* a tad less efficient, because of all the list functions.

*edit:* forced the accumulator.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a different solution using a fold, with a tuple `{Maybe a, Maybe a)` as the accumulator.  The algorithm is similar to dfeuer’s excellent answer.  It does not require a helper type, and the function to extract the solution is already in the `Prelude`. One disadvantage is that it does have an extra pattern match: there is an impossible state `(Nothing, Just _)` where the second-smallest element has been set but not the smallest, and we check for it in order for our patterns to be exhaustive, whereas dfeuer’s `Acc a` type only encoded valid program states.  This fall-through case won’t slow the program down at runtime, because it will never be reached. It’s possible that the compiler will be able to unbox the accumulator argument and get something slightly more efficient.

**ETA:** Willem Van Onsem gave a similar solution at the end of his answer.  It differs in calling the fold if and only if the list has at least two elements, which means there is only one pattern the fold function needs to match. That’s more efficient in most cases because the overhead of setting up the initial value of the accumulator only has to be done once, but the overhead of pattern-matching in the fold function has to be done once per element.  It also does not need `Maybe` inside the fold.  I’ll leave this one up in the hope that seeing several different approaches is helpful.

```
import Data.List (foldl')

secondSmallest :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
secondSmallest = snd . foldl' go (Nothing, Nothing) where
{- The accumulator of go is a pair whose first element is the smallest
 - element encountered so far and whose second element is the second-
 - smallest encountered so far.
 -}
  go (Nothing, Nothing) x = (Just x, Nothing)
  go (Just x, Nothing) y | y < x     = (Just y, Just x)
                         | otherwise = (Just x, Just y)
  go (Just x, Just y) z | z < x     = (Just z, Just x)
                        | z < y     = (Just x, Just z)
                        | otherwise = (Just x, Just y)
  go _ _ = error "Logic error: found second-smallest but not smallest element."
```

Comment: it's not that you don't have a helper type and an extractor; they are just inlined. same for my code. the looser the type, the shorter the code. :)

Comment: @WillNess Indeed. Again, not making any claim that this solution is “better,” but I am spelling out its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @WillNess I guess I’m a perfectionist. The top answer (currently Willem Van Onsem’s) is great, by the way. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a working non-solution. It depends on an minimum function I wrote a while ago. My minimum takes one parameter, a list. Your function seems to be looking for a minimum so here is mine. It would have to placed in a wrapper to meet all your requirements. It fails on `[]` and returns `x` given `[x]` so would again fail.

```
minf :: (Num b, Ord b) => [b] -> b
minf [x]    = x
minf (x:xs) = if x < head xs then minf $ x : tail xs else minf xs
```

How it is used is like such to produce the second smallest element. It finds the first smallest then excludes it from the list searched after it is found.

```
ls = [5,3,7,2,3,1]
minf [sd | ft <- [minf ls], sd <- ls,sd /= ft]
```

2

Comment: A potential problem with this approach is that if the two smallest elements are equal, then you will ignore the second one, and thus retur a larger element. Perhaps it is better to add this as a precondition in your answer.

Comment: But with `ls = [6,5,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6]` it still produces `2`. `minf` does not count. I am confused. `minf` produces one number. The first smallest number is identical to itself but `minf` only produces one. ??? 
`

Comment: that is because there are two `1`s in the list. As you can see in the question, if the list contains two such minimum values, the result is that minimum value.

Comment: I does not jibe with "second smallest" You asked "does a list of one element have a second smallest?" It does not have a second anything. Ones in [1,1,1] are all equally small, there is no smaller or larger. Equality cannot be at the same time less than or greater than. But, may well be a requirement. TY!